# How to make 'return false' prevent execution of successive functions in an inline onclick event handler?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following input field with an inline event handler containing multiple functions. I was hoping that if `reqField()` returned `false` the remaining functions would be cancelled, but this is not happening.

All that happens is that `reqField()` is terminated early and if there was a default action for an input field, it would be prevented. Is there anyway to achieve the result I'm after (termination of the remaining functions).

By the way, I can't just remove them from the `onclick` before `returning false` because they need to remain in place for the next `onblur` event.

```
function getnDisplayTextInputBox(id) {

var s   = document.getElementById(id);

s.setAttribute('onclick', '');

    var obj = getDataAttribs2Obj(id);
    var str = getParamStrFromDataObj(obj);

    s.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" data-param=\""+obj['param']+"\" id=\"edit\" value=\""+htmlentities(s.innerHTML)+"\" onblur=\"return reqField(this); postData('"+obj['sendtourl']+"', '"+str+"&spanid="+id+"&newVal='+this.value, 'replaceTextTextInputFieldWithValue(resp);', '','');\">";

    document.getElementById('edit').focus();

}
```

The above function replaces text in a `span` with an input field populated with the same text, when a user clicks on the original text. They can then edit the text, which is send to the server and saved `onbur`.

Some of the spans have an attribute `data-param='required'` and if so, the `reqField()` will require that the field is not empty and will `return false` if it is (after alerting the user to the problem with an alert box). Obviously, I don't want the next function in-line to fire, sending the empty field to the server for saving, or the one after, which swaps out the input box for plain-text in a `span`.

Comment: `return` ends your code and "returns" to whatever called it.

Comment: My suggestion is to lose the inline events, and use an event handler.  Store the function's return value in a variable.  Then use an `if` to see if you should end or continue.

Comment: @RocketHazmat So you mean set a global variable which could be checked by the following functions? I think that could work.

Comment: That's not what I was suggesting.  I was saying do this: `function(){ var go = func1();  if(go){ func2(); } }`, but I guess that *could* work too.

Comment: Thanks @RocketHazmat, I ended up using a global variable which is working great. You stimulatated the idea though. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

function getnDisplayTextInputBox(id) {

```
var s   = document.getElementById(id);

   s.setAttribute('onclick', '');

var obj = getDataAttribs2Obj(id);
var str = getParamStrFromDataObj(obj);

s.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" data-param=\""+obj['param']+"\" id=\"edit\" value=\""+htmlentities(s.innerHTML)+"\" onblur=\"if(this.value==''){return false;}else{return reqField(this); postData('"+obj['sendtourl']+"', '"+str+"&spanid="+id+"&newVal='+this.value, 'replaceTextTextInputFieldWithValue(resp);', '','');}\">";

document.getElementById('edit').focus();
```

}

Comment: Thanks. Interesting solution which I suspect would have solved my problem. I think I still prefer what I did though (set a global variable and check that in each of the following functions to determine whether to abort or not. +1 for a workable solution though.